# Sass Error: Undefined Variable, even though it is declared

Tags: sass

So I have installed and compiled Sass and it's all perfectly fine working. But I have tried to declare variables, which give me an error message, but I have no idea why.

```
$black: #333
$pale: #d2e1dd
$pink: #c69
$blue: #036

body
    background: $black
```

The error message is:

> Undefined variable: "$black"

Could it be that it has something to do with Ruby since I installed and compiled sass with it?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with Sass, in my case the error was because I included the variables file after the other file where I used them, you could try doing this, reorder files import, make the variables file at the top.